# How to count the number of matches when executing query SELECT WHERE LIKE?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I count the number of matches when executing a query like the following one:

EDIT: sorry for the bad explanation I tought you guys would understand it.
here is an update.

```
$thingsilike = explode(" ", $search); 
foreach($thingsilike as $things){
$array[] = "keywords LIKE '%$things%'";
}
```

lets say the following sentence "I like apples and oranges" is placed into the array. the array would look like this

```
$array('I', 'like', 'apples', 'and', 'oranges');

query = ("SELECT * FROM row WHERE thingspeoplelike LIKE .implode(' OR', $array);
```

the query would then search for every keyword in 'thingspeoplelike'
what I would like to know is how to find out how many matches there are with the words
so lets say there are three sentences in thingspeoplelike:

first one 'I like apples and oranges'
the amount of matches there are would be 5

second 'I like apples and pineapples'
the amound of matches would be 4

third sentence 'I like apples' 
the amount of matches would be 3

I would like to know how I can find out and count the amount of matches again sorry for the bad explanation and thanks in advance guys!

Comment: post more of your PHP code - this is what `rowCount` is for: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: what do you mean by `implode(' OR',$array)`, exactly what you want to do?

Comment: user3188287 wants to combine the elements of $array with ' OR ' as seperator to use it as LIKE clause

Comment: @scrowler sorry for the bad explanation posted more code and a better explanation.

Comment: @SumitBijvani sorry edited the post with a better explanation

Comment: @PaulFacklam sorry not what I was thinking about thanks tough. I edited with a better explanation maybe you can help now

Comment: Agree. This is definitely something completely different. Not sure if you can do that with less effort. May be an inverted search index like solr would be a better option in achieving your goal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of lines that match your query or rather the input of your array then simply use:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM row WHERE things LIKE ".implode(' OR ', $array)
```

**UPDATE AFTER QUESTION CLARIFICATION:**

```
/* split the input sentence */
$thingsilike = explode(" ", $search);

$result = /* Get all sentences (thingspeoplelike) from row and store it in $result */

foreach($result as $sentence) {

    $count = 0;
    $parts = explode(" ", $sentence);

    foreach($thingsilike as $keyword) {

        if(in_array($keyword, $parts) == true) {

            $count = $count + 1;
        }
    }

    echo "Found {$count} matches for result '{$sentence}'";
}
```

I hope that is what you looked for...

Comment: What is wrong with this solution? If there is another goal then the question has to be defined more precisely.